# Resize WPF UserControl without all children "jumping around"

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, animation, storyboard

Is there a way to resize a WPF UserControl in such a way that the child controls don't flop around?

I've got this Storyboard:

```
<Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Storyboard.TargetName="MyUserControl" To="145" From="0" Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>
```

This works great; it takes my control from Height Zero to Height 145 -- the problem is that as the Height property changes, all of the child controls inside start jumping around, I suspect, due to their HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlighment properties. Is there a way I can disable that until the animation is finished?

I'm trying to create the illusion of this UserControl "sliding" into view -- so I'm open to other approaches if I'm going about this wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is "jumping around" because every time the `Height` of the control is changed all the containing controls reposition themselves according to the new available space.

To achieve the desired effect you should use `RenderTransform` instead of changing the actual `Height` of the control.

Here is how you can do that. First, add `ScaleTransform` as a value of `RenderTransform` property on your control:

```
<MyUserControl.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0" />
</MyUserControl.RenderTransform>
```

Then, modify target property of your animation to change the `ScaleY` property of the transform:

```
<Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="MyUserControl" To="145" Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>
```

**Update:**

Another way to achieve the slide-into-view effect is to use `TranslateTransform` with negative `Y` value:

```
<MyUserControl.RenderTransform>
   <TranslateTransform Y="-1000" />
</MyUserControl.RenderTransform>
```

And then, animate its `Y` property to 0:

```
<Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="MyUserControl" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: This works, the controls no longer jump around; however, they now appear stretched until the transform is complete. I'm accepting because its much better than what I had, but if you have any thoughts on avoiding the stretch that'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

When you animate the Height or Width the UserControl tells its children also to readjust, that is the way the layout system works in WPF. The 'Jumping around' will really depends upon the kind of Layout (Grid,StackPanel etc..) you using.

But looks like, for your scenario it will be better to use  RenderTransform ScaleTransform ScaleY animation instead of animating the Height. Rendertransform wont disturb your layout arrangements of the UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Pavlov's updated answer, I had to use a blank CompositeTransform instead. Maybe it is due to using the latest Blend for Visual Studio 2012 update 1, but this worked (targeting Windows Phone 8):

```
    <MyUserControl.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform />
    </MyUserControl.RenderTransform>
```